# How to get system information in windows with c++

Tags: c++, windows

I want to get my system hardware information with c++ code.

So how to get system information in windows with c++ ?

Comment: What exact problem did you face while trying to get the system info? Could you show some code sample and point to the problematic line?

Comment: I think you're probably looking for [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page). But only probably because (a) your question is not explicit and (b) WMI is so comprehensive and complex it's hard to recognise it as the place to get simple information. I have spent over 1 hour searching the web, and I'm still not 100% sure that WMI is what I should use to tell me what CPU type and operating system I have...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `GetSystemInfo` function to obtain hardware information such as the OEM identifier, processor type, page size, and so on.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

void main()
{
   SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;

   // Copy the hardware information to the SYSTEM_INFO structure. 

   GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo); 

   // Display the contents of the SYSTEM_INFO structure. 

   printf("Hardware information: \n");  
   printf("  OEM ID: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwOemId);
   printf("  Number of processors: %u\n", 
      siSysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors); 
   printf("  Page size: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwPageSize); 
   printf("  Processor type: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwProcessorType); 
   printf("  Minimum application address: %lx\n", 
      siSysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress); 
   printf("  Maximum application address: %lx\n", 
      siSysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress); 
   printf("  Active processor mask: %u\n", 
      siSysInfo.dwActiveProcessorMask); 
}
```

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724423(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/124624/

Answer (score 2):

**Processor Info**

Use `void WINAPI GetSystemInfo(..)` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381(v=vs.85).aspx))

This returns a `SYSTEM_INFO` struct that contains:

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_INFO {
  union {
    DWORD  dwOemId;
    struct {
      WORD wProcessorArchitecture;
      WORD wReserved;
    };
  };
  DWORD     dwPageSize;
  LPVOID    lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
  LPVOID    lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
  DWORD_PTR dwActiveProcessorMask;
  DWORD     dwNumberOfProcessors;
  DWORD     dwProcessorType;
  DWORD     dwAllocationGranularity;
  WORD      wProcessorLevel;
  WORD      wProcessorRevision;
} SYSTEM_INFO;
```

**Enumerate devices**

Use the `IPortableDeviceManager` interface to enumerate devices. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319331(v=vs.85).aspx) describes This API in details.

Here is a code snippet from that page:

```
// Create PortableDeviceManager

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PortableDeviceManager,
                              NULL,
                              CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                              IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPortableDeviceManager));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("! Failed to CoCreateInstance CLSID_PortableDeviceManager, hr = 0x%lx\n",hr);
    return;
}

// Get number of devices

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pPortableDeviceManager->GetDevices(NULL, &cPnPDeviceIDs);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("! Failed to get number of devices on the system, hr = 0x%lx\n",hr);
    }
}

// Report the number of devices found.  NOTE: we will report 0, if an error
// occured.

printf("\n%d Windows Portable Device(s) found on the system\n\n", cPnPDeviceIDs);

// Enumerate the device information

if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (cPnPDeviceIDs > 0))
{
    pPnpDeviceIDs = new (std::nothrow) PWSTR[cPnPDeviceIDs];
    if (pPnpDeviceIDs != NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwIndex = 0;

        hr = pPortableDeviceManager->GetDevices(pPnpDeviceIDs, &cPnPDeviceIDs);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // For each device found, display the devices friendly name,
            // manufacturer, and description strings.
            for (dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < cPnPDeviceIDs; dwIndex++)
            {
                printf("[%d] ", dwIndex);
                DisplayFriendlyName(pPortableDeviceManager, pPnpDeviceIDs[dwIndex]);
                printf("    ");
                DisplayManufacturer(pPortableDeviceManager, pPnpDeviceIDs[dwIndex]);
                printf("    ");
                DisplayDescription(pPortableDeviceManager, pPnpDeviceIDs[dwIndex]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("! Failed to get the device list from the system, hr = 0x%lx\n",hr);
        }
    }
}

// Free memory used to store the information

for (dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < cPnPDeviceIDs; dwIndex++)
{
    CoTaskMemFree(pPnpDeviceIDs[dwIndex]);
    pPnpDeviceIDs[dwIndex] = NULL;
}

// Delete the array of PWSTR pointers
delete [] pPnpDeviceIDs;
pPnpDeviceIDs = NULL;
```