# How to get the OS information at C

Tags: c

I am coding a program and I wonder on which OS my program will run.

How can I get the OS info (ex - Windows 10 or not) at the code?

※ I just want to show different results whether it's Windows 10 or not

Comment: Do you care about it at compile time or runtime? Those are two very different things

Comment: OS is easy, since you typically compile for a specific target OS. This information is available at compile-time (usually in the form of preprocessor macros). But if you mean OS *version* (like Windows 8 or Windows 10) then that's a different matter. That information has to be gotten at run-time, and of course depends on the OS itself (Windows versus different variants of Linux versus macOS etc.). Please edit your question to specify more details about what you need and what you have tried.

Comment: You could use the environment variables : `int main(int ac, const char **av, const char **envp)`. They are all in the `envp` pointer. (note that if you want to edit it you need to copy the environment)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer Zimmer  But, I can't find out if it's win10 or 7

Comment: Sorry, I don't know windows environment variables. (linux > all xD).
But after a 12-second google search, I found [this](http://c-program-example.com/2012/01/c-program-to-get-the-system-information.html)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer [Error] sys/utsname.h: No such file or directory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023477/how-to-get-system-information-in-windows-with-c

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer it still doesn't allow me to get the version

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
printf("Windows\n");
#else
printf("Not Windows\n");
#endif
```

Comment: Does that differentiate between, say, Windows 10 and Windows 7?

Comment: @TanoFotang It doesn't