# How can I get Installed Memory Information?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, c++17

I'm currently trying to get information on the installed memory in a c++ program I'm writing using `<windows.h>` . I'm able to get things like total number of threads, cpu base clock speed, and installed physical memory. Does anyone know if there is a way for me to get hardware information like operating frequency on each installed memory stick?

I'm able to get the total amount of installed memory with something like ...

```cpp
unsigned long long total_memory_kilobytes = 0;
GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(&total_memory_kilobytes);
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getphysicallyinstalledsystemmemory?redirectedfrom=MSDN

But I have not been able to find anything in the API's about getting specific device information.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023477/how-to-get-system-information-in-windows-with-c/47023542

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use [Win32_PhysicalMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory) to get the information.

Comment: @Tyler Weiss Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.